# make text act like a checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a form, is it possible to make a textstring act like a checkbox and for example  highlight it when clicked, without actually showing the checkbox?

edit:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.fake-check').on('click',function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).removeClass('checked').children('input').val('');
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('checked').children('input').val($(this).data('val'));
      }
    });
});
</script>

<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<a class="fake-check" data-val="somevalue">Something<input type="text"   name="somefield"></a>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:php], and is entirely to do with CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, given the following HTML:

```
​<input type="checkbox" id="test" /><label for="test">Click to check</label>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the CSS:

```
​label {
    color: #f00;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: #0f0;
}
​
```

```css
label {
  color: #f00;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" checked/>
<label for="test">Click to check</label>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7rmmu/).

This is, of course, dependent on browsers implementing the `:checked` pseudo-class.

I've used the attribute-equals notation to specify the `label` elements that follow a checked `input` of `type="checkbox"`, but as only a `checkbox` or `radio` can *be* selected, that specificity might be safely omitted.

You can also, in compliant browsers, use the same approach in concert with the `::after` pseudo-element and its `content` property, change the text to reflect the state of the checkbox. For example, with the following HTML:

```
​<input type="checkbox" id="test" /><label for="test">Click to</label>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the CSS:

```
​label {
    color: #f00;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: #0f0;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: ' check';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    content: ' uncheck';
}
​
```

```css
label {
  color: #f00;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #0f0;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: ' check';
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  content: ' uncheck';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" checked/>
<label for="test">Click to</label>
```

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
- [`::before``::after` pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content).
- [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery and do this pretty easily:

HTML:

```
<a class="fake-check" data-val="somevalue">
    Something
    <input type="hidden" name="somefield">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.checked { background: red; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.fake-check').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
      $(this).removeClass('checked').children('input').val('');
  }else{
      $(this).addClass('checked').children('input').val($(this).data('val'));
  }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vZVNC/

Comment: ok, but I would actually want to retrieve a true or false when the form is submitted.

Comment: No problem - updated it so you just include the `data-val` which is the value the field gets when 'checked', it gets put into the `input` field as a value so you can grab it when you submit the form.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vZVNC/1/ I left the input as `text` instead of hidden so you can see the value getting added/removed

Comment: The benefit with this method is that it can be applied to a series of these 'fake checkboxes' and each one can have it's own value, name, etc since it's replicating the checkbox with a hidden field.

Comment: thanks alot m8. Looks pretty straight forward. Still... I don't get it to work. What am I missing? I uploaded my code in the original post.

Comment: You need to call it, so create a load call $(function(){ // PUT YOUR CODE HERE // }); and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but only on CSS3 browsers:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" class="hideMe"> ​<label for="a">Something</label>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
.hideMe {
    height:0;
    width:0;
    visibility:hidden;   
}    

input:checked + label {
    background-color:#e0e0e0
}
```

Comment: Good, using of java script or jquery is complex. You simpaly solved it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var is_highlighted = false;
    function textclicked(text){
        if(is_highlighted == false){
            text.style.background = '#FFFF99';
            is_highlighted = true;
        }
        else{
            text.style.background = 'none';
            is_highlighted = false;
        }

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:textclicked(this)">some text which act like checkbox</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```